# Transact SQL help

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Having trouble getting this to work have a web app using visual studios 2010 on front end and sql2008r2 backend gets this error

"Error inserting record.Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I have these fields and datatypes

```
StartDate value=date
StartTime value=varchar(8)
EndDate value = date
EndTime value=varchar(8)
```

I am trying to add both startdate + StartTime into a customstartdate field but it is getting an error converting

```
convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,101) +
   stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),@StartTime,109 ),15),7,7, ' ' ),
    convert(varchar(10),@EndDate, 101) +
   stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),@EndTime,109 ),15),7,7, ' ' ),
```

Comment: If you use the default format of SQL, then I think you should check whether you datetime string is exactly the same as: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` Hope this helps

Comment: This should be a standard debugging task.  Break down that mess in the second code block and find out where the error is.

Comment: The title of this post is meaningless

Comment: almost as meaningless as you wasting time to actually say how meaningless the title was

Comment: spacemoses im sorry I read a lot and try and learn how to do things on my own but the reason people open these forums is so when im stuck i can get help, if you are going to tell me it is "standard debugging" why bother even being on the forums when you know its going to be full of questions from people that are just learning this stuff we are not all geniuses like yourself

Comment: @Micheal - Apologies on being blunt.  However, I would be more inclined to ask forum questions such as "What does a T-SQL convert() function do?" or "What the hell is stuff()?".  Before firing off your debugging questions, break it down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test your conversions in SQL Management Studio to see what it returns.

```
declare @StartDate datetime = getdate()
declare @EndDate datetime = getdate()
declare @StartTime varchar(8) = '10:00:00'
declare @EndTime varchar(8) = '11:00:00'

select
convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,101) +
   stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),@StartTime,109 ),15),7,7, ' ' ) as StartDate,
    convert(varchar(10),@EndDate, 101) +
   stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),@EndTime,109 ),15),7,7, ' ' ) as EndDate
```

Result

```
StartDate           EndDate
------------------- -------------------
03/23/201110:00:    03/23/201111:00:
```

You could also break your conversion into parts so you see what happens

```
select
  convert(varchar(10), @StartDate,101) as DatePart, 
  convert(varchar(26),@StartTime,109) as Time26,
  right(convert(varchar(26),@StartTime,109 ),15) as Time15,
  stuff(right(convert(varchar(26),@StartTime,109 ),15),7,7, ' ' ) as TimeStuff
```

Result

```
DatePart   Time26                     Time15          TimeStuff
---------- -------------------------- --------------- ---------
03/23/2011 10:00:00                   10:00:00        10:00:
```

This is what I would do. The result is a datetime.

```
select
  convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 101)+' '+@StartTime) as StartDate,
  convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 101)+' '+@EndTime) as EndDate
```

Result

```
StartDate               EndDate
----------------------- -----------------------
2011-03-23 10:00:00.000 2011-03-23 11:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will break it down and see what is going on really appreciate it